# Using MVVM show new window and get updates data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, interface, modal-dialog

I'm working on a WPF MVVM application. I'm showing some data in a datagrid. I've two buttons to Add and Edit the selected record.  I've data in ViewModel and I've to show another window (view) and make sure that ViewModels should have no information about views. 
Where should I create its view and viewmodel? 
How to get the data back and update datagrid?
How can I achieve this in MVVM?
We have not yet decided to use any framework, so I've to create my own interface.

Comment: is your "another window" like a modal dialog? That is to say, is it a separate window, that holds the focus until it is closed again, and then the focus returns to the main window?

Comment: Yes, that is a modal dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: This ended up being quite a long answer - please ask me if anything is unclear*

The implementation of dialog windows is a contentious issue in MVVM designs, and different people use different approaches.

Like you, I've decided not to use any framework and implement most things by hand. When it comes to dialog windows, I choose to be pragmatic about my implementation of MVVM, by launching the Dialog Window from inside my ViewModel. Also, I allow each Dialog ViewModel to have a reference to the Window it is displayed in, so it can close it when appropriate (details below). This breaks some of the strict MVVM "rules", but it gets the job done.

The main downside of this is that it might break unit testing if you are testing something that goes through a dialog. However, you can go a long way without running into that problem and it has not bothered me yet.

I've built up a bit of a library of dialog ViewModels which I can easily extend. It's way too much code to post here, but I'll show you the highlights.

**Base ViewModel for Dialogs**

Each of my dialog windows has a ViewModel that inherits from `DialogViewModelBase`, which is similiar to my regular `ViewModelBase` in that it provides support for `INotifyPropertyChanged` etc. The interesting part is this public method, which I call from wherever to launch the Dialog:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Creates window instance for this dialog viewmodel and displays it, getting the dialog result.
/// </summary>
public void ShowDialogWindow()
{
    // This is a property of the DialogViewModelBase class - thus, each DialogViewModel holds a reference to its own DialogWindow:
    this.DialogWindow = new Dialogs.Views.DialogWindow();
    // Tell the DialogWindow to display this ViewModel:
    this.DialogWindow.DataContext = this;
    // Launch the Window, using a method of the Window baseclass, that only returns when the window is closed:
    this.DialogWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Window launched in the above method will close when its `Window.DialogResult` property is set. This is why the `DialogWindow` is a property of the `DialogViewModelBase` class - when the subclassing dialog `ViewModel` wants to close the dialog window, it simply sets the result:

```cs
protected void CloseDialogWithResult(bool dialogWindowResult)
{
    // Setting this property automatically closes the dialog window:
    this.DialogWindow.DialogResult = dialogWindowResult;
}
```

**Host Window for Dialog Views**

The `Dialogs.Views.DialogWindow` class that the `ShowDialogWindow` method instantiates is defined in XAML and is a subclass of `Window`. It has two important features. The first is that it's primary content element is simply a `ContentControl` that binds to the current context. This allows me to define different `Views` for different subclasses of `DialogViewModelBase`, and the `DialogWindow` will host the corresponding `View` based on the type of the context:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" /> <!-- In reality this is inside a border etc but its simplified here for demonstration -->
```

The second important feature of the `DialogWindow` XAML is that it defines which dialog `Views` go with which dialog `ViewModels`. Here is a sample:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- DEFAULT ViewModel-View TEMPLATES -->

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dialogs:YesNoMessageBoxDialogViewModel}">
        <views:MessageBoxView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dialogs:ErrorDialogViewModel}">
        <views:ErrorDialogView/>            
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

What all this does, is that I can define dialogs as subclasses to `DialogViewModelBase` and implement a `View` for each, and then tell `DialogWindow` which `View` its `ContentControl` must show for which dialog `ViewModel`.

**Launching a Dialog and getting results**

Below is a sample from one of my application `ViewModels`, in which I launch a Dialog Window that allows the user to select an Asset Type for creation:

```cs
public void CreateNewAsset()
{
    // Instantiate desired Dialog ViewModel:
    Dialogs.NewAssetTypeSelectionDialogViewModel dialog = new Dialogs.NewAssetTypeSelectionDialogViewModel();

    // Launch Dialog by calling method on Dialog base class:
    dialog.ShowDialogWindow();

    // Execution will halt here until the Dialog window closes...

    // The user's selection is stored in a property on the dialog ViewModel, and can now be retrieved:
    CalculatorBase.AssetTypeEnum newAssetType = dialog.AssetType;

    switch (newAssetType)
    {
        // Do stuff based on user's selection...
    }
}
```

*PS: I should really write a blog entry about this - when I do, I will post the link here, as the blog entry will probably have more complete code samples.*

Comment: Thanks for the post, the book MVVM Survival Guide for Enterprise Architectures in Silverligt and WPF by Ryan Vice & Muhammad Shujaat Siddiqi shows a similar method, with more detail.  For all those interested in the technique.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are handling the data. I will assume that changes made in the popup window can be accepted only when user clicks something like save in other case they should be discarded. 
So firstly, I would suggest using MVC approach as controller is perfect for such tasks. You build viewmodels in it, assign them o views and show the views. VM's simply keeps data and commands, commands execute methods are kept in controller. In other words you have singleton class which manages your VM's and views. 
You should check out [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework. It offers great things like view regios where you can inject different user controls on the runtime, commanding and MVC layering out of the box alongside IOC and DI patterns.